# How to start a NamedPipeServer within a Windows Explorer ShellExtension in a correct way

Tags: c++, named-pipes, shell-extensions

I have to implement a NamedPipeServer in our Windows Explorer ShellExtension which contains a ContextMenuExtension and a IconOverlayExtension.
The NamedPipeServer itself is no problem but i have no idea where within the shellextension dll to start the NamedPipeServer.

I've read that it is no good idea to try to start the server from DllMain. Nevertheless i tried this and it leads to a deadlock (as promised).

Now i have no clou if there is another entry point which is called once the dll is loaded by the explorer where i can start the server.

My question is if there is a possibility to achieve what i'm trying.

Comment: No, there's nothing specific to Explorer or Shell extensions in this case, you'll have to start your server the first time you're called for example.

Comment: I'm curious, why do your shell extensions need a named pipe server in the first place? I would probably just split out the pipe server into a separate background service and have the shell extensions communicate with it as needed.

Comment: The reason is that the clients (every windows user on the system can start the client) has to subscribe to the shellextension that the extension knows which client is running and can ask the clients for information (e.g. which overlay has to be shown).